# How to get today's date given a specific location/timezone with moment-timezone

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I know how to get today's date.

```
`require('moment-timezone')().format('Y-DD-MM')`
```

However, how would I get today's date in a specific timezone?

Such as `America/Los_Angeles` where today might be one day behind GMT.
If this is January 1st, 4am GMT, then in Los Angeles it is Dec 31st, 9pm. which is what I'm trying to get (`2018-12-31` and not `2019-1-1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`moment.tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/)

> The moment.tz constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```js
var nowInLosAngeles = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log( nowInLosAngeles.format('Y-DD-MM') );
console.log( nowInLosAngeles.format() );
console.log( nowInLosAngeles.valueOf() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```